# Low level control of system speaker in Windows

Tags: windows, audio

Is there a way to take complete control of the motherboard speaker in Windows? So, instead of calling a function like this:

```
beep(durationMs, frequency);
```

I can use:

```
beepContinuous(frequency);
```

So all I have to specify is a frequency and it will output the correct voltage to play that frequency.

Comment: well, I don't see any reason why you'd do it.. you could set something like a loop or a timer to continuously start new beeps (giving then the feel that it's continuous).. I guess there won't be any noise in the possible 'gaps'.. but I'm not sure.

Comment: I've already tried this, it sounds terrible. At least on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good discussion of a bunch of audio API choices on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314522/what-is-the-best-c-sound-api-for-windows).  The most basic technique is to use the `waveOut` calls in the [Waveform Audio API set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743833%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I am not sure that this answers the question. The OP is talking about the internal speaker, i.e. the primitive speaker (or "beeper") on the motherboard, not the computer's normal audio output. I am not sure that the waveOut API functions can use the internal speaker. Can they?

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand - On my laptop, both `Beep` and `waveOut` refer to the same device - I hear both on the headphone jack.  There's a couple of functions that allow enumerating all the devices: `waveOutGetNumDevs` and `waveOutGetDevCaps`.  I'm not sure that modern PCs still have a separate speaker with that simple speaker driver.